# Pass multiple input values to a function to update an image

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, onchange

I want to change an image depending on what two input values have been entered. How would this be done dynamically with two separate inputs? Here's my code so far.

```js
function twoinputs() {
  var size1 = document.getElementById("size1").value;
  var size2 = document.getElementById("size2").value;
  var getValue = size1.value;
  var getValue2 = size2.value;
  if (getValue == "1" && getValue2 == "1") {
    document.getElementById('optimus').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.orderofinterbeing.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/light-forest.jpg')";
  } else if (getValue == "2" && getValue2 == "2") {
    document.getElementById('optimus').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/coniferous-forest.jpg')";
  }
}
twoselects();
```

```css
p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="prime" src="images/image_small.jpg">
<form>
  Select image size:
  <input id='size1' name='size1' onchange="twoinputs()">
  <input id='size2' name='size2' onchange="twoinputs()">
</form>
<p id="optimus"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, inputs are self closing, so change the HTML to

```
<img class="prime" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
<form>
    Select image size:
    <input id='size1' name='size1'>
    <input id='size2' name='size2'>
</form>
<p id="optimus"></p>
```

In the script, the problem is that you're getting the value twice, and you've mixed up the names of the function and some variables.

You could also use proper event handlers

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("size1");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("size2");
var image = document.getElementById('optimus');

function twoinputs() {
    var size1 = +elem1.value;
    var size2 = +elem2.value;

    if (size1 === 1 && size2 === 1) {
        image.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.orderofinterbeing.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/light-forest.jpg')";
    } else if (size1 == 2 && size2 == 2) {
        image.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/coniferous-forest.jpg')";
    }
}

twoinputs();

elem1.addEventListener('change', twoinputs, false);
elem2.addEventListener('change', twoinputs, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/g0yr0wed/)

Comment: `change` event ? I guess it should be `input` or `keyup`

Comment: @RayonDabre - depends on what the OP wants, he/she is using `change` now ?

Comment: Yes this is great and will help me get going in the right direction thanks for the help. What does the + mean before elem1.value and elem2.value? I've never seen it before

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok, but you have .value twice so size1.value will not have the attribute value, in other words:

```
function twoinputs() {
var size1 = document.getElementById("size1");
var size2 = document.getElementById("size2");
var getValue = size1.value;
var getValue2 = size2.value;**
if (getValue == "1" && getValue2 == "1") {
document.getElementById('optimus').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.orderofinterbeing.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/light-forest.jpg')";
} else if (getValue == "2" && getValue2 == "2") {
document.getElementById('optimus').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/coniferous-forest.jpg')";
}
}
twoselects();
```